# How to only let Edit Text accept Letters which are in Textview

Tags: java, android-studio, textview, android-edittext

I have an edit text however I only want letters which are in another Text view to be typeable. For example if the Text view say Hello Only H,E,L and O should be Typeable.

Comment: `android:digits="helo"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code you can get it to only accept your String

```
android:digits="@string/YourString"
```